# Preserving generics in TypeScript mapped types

Tags: javascript, typescript, generics, mapped-types

I have a class, whose instance methods are handlers, each of which represents an operation, taking a reference as the input and assign the output to the second parameter. A proxy object is generated by a third party library so that the handlers can be called directly.

```
type InputRef<T> = {
  current: T,
};
type OutputRef<T> = {
  current?: T,
};

class Original {
  increment(input: InputRef<number>, output: OutputRef<number>) {
    const { current: inValue } = input;
    
    output.current = inValue + 1;
  }
}

type Mapper<Fn> = Fn extends (input: InputRef<infer U>, output: OutputRef<infer V>) => unknown ? (input: U) => V : never;
type MyProxyGeneratedByThirdPartyJs = { [FnName in keyof Original]: Mapper<Original[FnName]> };

declare const proxy: MyProxyGeneratedByThirdPartyJs;

const result = proxy.increment(3); // 4
```

However, the mapper does not work when the handler involves generic types, e.g.,

```
class Original {
  toBox<T>(input: InputRef<T>, output: OutputRef<{ boxed: T }>) {
    const { current: inValue } = input;

    output.current = { boxed: inValue };
  }
}
```

Using the same way above, the type of `proxy` only involves `unknown`, and the generic information `T` is lost.

Ideally, I want `proxy` to be of type

```
{
  toBox<T>(input: T): { boxed: T },
}
```

instead of

```
{
  toBox(input: unknown): { boxed: unknown },
}
```

Is there any way achieving this?

Comment: @jcalz Thanks so much. Seems it’s what I’m looking for. Is there any suggested workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not currently possible in TypeScript. In order to express what you're doing to [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) functions at the type level, you'd need *higher kinded types* as requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#1213](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213), but these are not directly supported.  The [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) definition of `Mapper<Fn>` infers `U` as the input type and `V` as the output type, but there is no capacity for the compiler to see or represent any higher-order relationship between them when `Fn` is generic.

There is *some* [support for transforming generic function types into other generic function types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#higher-order-type-inference-from-generic-functions), but this only happens in very specific circumstances.  The transformation needs to happen at least partially at the value level (there must be a function *value* which transforms one generic function type into another when called, not just the *type* of that function) so there will be JS code emitted.  And the transformation only works for a single function at a time, so an object of functions cannot be mapped at once without losing the generics.

Still, to show that there is some ability to do this, here is how one might approach it:

```
function proxySingleFunction<U, V>(
    f: (input: InputRef<U>, output: OutputRef<V>) => any
): (input: U) => V {
    return function (input: U) {
        const o: OutputRef<V> = {};
        f({ current: input }, o);
        const ret = o.current;
        if (ret === undefined) throw new Error("OH NO");
        return ret;
    }
}
```

The type of `proxySingleFunction()` is

```
// function proxySingleFunction<U, V>(
//   f: (input: InputRef<U>, output: OutputRef<V>) => any
// ): (input: U) => V
```

which looks similar to what you're doing with `Mapper<Fn>`.  Then, if you *call* `proxySingleFunction()`, it will produce outputs of the relevant type:

```
const increment = proxySingleFunction(Original.prototype.increment);
// const increment: (input: number) => number

const toBox = proxySingleFunction(Original.prototype.toBox);
// const toBox: <T>(input: T) => { boxed: T; }
```

You can see that `toBox` is generic, as desired.  Then you could pacakge these output functions in a single `proxy` object and use it:

```
const proxy = {
    increment, toBox
}

console.log(proxy.increment(1).toFixed(1)) // "2.0"
console.log(proxy.toBox("a").boxed.toUpperCase()) // "A"
```

---

So that's great and it works.  But it requires that you emit JavaScript for each method you want to transform.  If you already have such a transformed object from a third party and just want to represent the typings, the closest you can get is to lie to the compiler via [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) so that it thinks you're doing the transformations when you're actually not:

```
// pretend this function exists
declare const psf: <U, V>(
    f: (input: InputRef<U>, output: OutputRef<V>) => any
) => (input: U) => V;

// pretend you're using it to create a proxy object
const myProxyType = (true as false) || {
    increment: psf(Original.prototype.increment),
    toBox: psf(Original.prototype.toBox)
}

// get the pretend type of that object
type MyProxyGeneratedByThirdPartyJs = typeof myProxyType;
/* type MyProxyGeneratedByThirdPartyJs = {
  increment: (input: number) => number;
  toBox: <T>(input: T) => { boxed: T; };
} */
```

I don't see this as a big win over just writing out these types manually in the first place, so I don't know that I'd recommend it.  It's just the closest I can imagine getting to what you want with the language as it currently is.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.9.4&ssl=17&ssc=45&pln=16&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgdmArsAShAZgHgCoD4oC8UA3gFBQVQDGiATrRHMAFxTYA0pAvgNymiQoAeWRJUGHPiJlK1OgyYB+Vh259SVADYBDAM67htAJYBzI3G2aS5SuaoMAto2AAKc2NbwxaLHEQOAIwhaXHYoAHtRZFYRYG8JP0Dg3ABKa1lZKnC4XWASOXpnVnMANUtEaC5CKHdkdQzKSLjkADoaQqZq0vLoAGooAEY+WS4bCmBwgCFwgA9JNwRo2EXxLDwwpo9hKNXMYigA2YgAExUoLlT0hups3Pz2hRYauDLNCvOulfrrzdaH52q+0OMxOxRePXOw0oo24pFI6EQcCowCM2SgYFosxAAGVzCZNBAAGKI5GouCYACqYRKuBcYyg6FYCy2XmQPkpoQiOxiO3ZNLSBHw2jgIFIKSZtSeFIF+BKVwoDGAdDgDJJKLRzKW0vlGSyOTy4R5zV2NMBvHpsnQLn2-yYYLE5w2KShDT1d0V1XCbXkzhdGSM6CgLg9BFDUERxww5hOaWAAAtMQB3KBwCDJgCi9HCtBcACIhAAJKAAOSEuedFsoiuVUEVftGowA9I3VUj1SqMVjcXB8US1WTKdTaaRm5RGUHJZ4VuyKZzfk9YvEsPzCEKRSOW+KJytWNrBVASnCNLc8nZHACiJ2Zji8QTiW2yS4hMYzBZNC1OxMBBAWmeIE4mArUc3VPJFzztbctkSIJaBlFN-BguEQKgCZphmaorxvHs737bInxfcxLA-TEv3AH9UNmICW2QiiZlYeZJzYOCgSOU42B4c4kJPdFMWvQF6T-ADgDCWjYWPHJwgJFpNHCEwXEw38wP-ZwXAGFIWgmQkjBBY5VJSNJR1zAAmFoAAZc3E3RJJ-GS5IU2i820csWmBE4NPCCkwEgWgAGE9AgFx9KgQyAEELJHAAqfgyKgABZbQvOCTBCSkKBCSgCAZmARhjgMTUnlZXZzHQYIoFnDZuW2Y12WK0qV33REAGs4HCRMVUUSCtTguVWFTAA3YI+G-OKQAABV4kAAHFGGCbRsuOSYQGwOMjFoY5Ru0WhQAAKQMaQoAAbQAaWeKBGogEBwkDZ9TEIzQAF1WHixLaEwG7X0sY77vwc1SEjLRNugZDMKesaJum1NaDmk5FuW1b1s2nbdHUZCGF0RBNDyS8JsU+xlKYFwAGZnWClsABY4Qixs4QsJxdDAbQqGgCkTDjHV-p0Bgbn1dFdHHQcD2Ha4GQlHdliXDkKuNI0JfqtdRVkOD8t3bq-WQhwwaxbAYqIFxgFod49AZSxdAgNIAB9zZ1WRBKKXmrXeu7iPCUjIFx8DgBSThhdo1gwD5-DbrfZ3XfIqZKPpUZZGG2LNevCHZvm2GVrWjatpAXbqm-K6oA18atbIv1GwilCYtj-P45mqGk6WlOEfTzPpErW2IOV+Cklg1d25gv1xnDuioAYsXsGYg5WJUDjzRGKAqbEoA)